# softwareupdate shows 2 updates for Command Line Tools - get rid of one entry

Tags: macos, command-line, xcode, software-update

I am on macOS Catalina 10.15.6 (19G2021) and `softwareupdate` as well as graphical "Softwareupdate" in "System settings" show **two** updates for Command Line Tools:

```
$ softwareupdate --list
Software Update Tool

Finding available software
Software Update found the following new or updated software:
* Label: Command Line Tools beta 5 for Xcode-12.0
    Title: Command Line Tools beta 5 for Xcode, Version: 12.0, Size: 442912K, Recommended: YES,
* Label: Safari14.0CatalinaAuto-14.0
    Title: Safari, Version: 14.0, Size: 65417K, Recommended: YES,
* Label: Command Line Tools for Xcode-12.0
    Title: Command Line Tools for Xcode, Version: 12.0, Size: 429595K, Recommended: YES,
```

**beta 5** was proposed to me for a couple of weeks now, but I did not want to install it.

Why did I end up with **beta 5** and how do I get rid of the duplicate here?

Answer (score 0):

I found one way to get rid of the duplicate by executing: `softwareupdate -i "Command Line Tools for Xcode-12.0"`.

Now **beta 5** is gone as well.

Comment: Feel free to ask your follow on question (which I have edited out) as a [follow on question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) if no one sees to provide a new answer after my edits today bump it to the top of the main page.